# Contrapositive of Analysis Theorems

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have a longstanding issue about how to construct contrapositives that I can't seem to resolve on my own.  In general, if $Q \rightarrow P$ is true, then so is $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$.  What I often find confusing when constructing the contrapositive is deciding upon the terms that will receive the negation. For example, consider this simple analysis theorem:

If $A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}$ are countable sets, then the union $A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots \cup A_{m}$ is countable.

The form of the contrapositive is

$\neg(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots \cup A_{m}$ countable)$\rightarrow \neg(A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}$ are countable sets).

In this case, does the negation of the premise in the contrapositive apply to the union operators or just to the countability property? And does the negation of the conclusion apply to what seems to be an implied universal quantifier on the $A_{i}$'s? In other words, is the contrapositive

$A_{1} \cap A_{2}\cap \ldots \cap A_{n}$ uncountable $\rightarrow$ there exists $A_{i} \in \{{A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}\}}$ that is uncountable

or

$A_{1} \cap A_{2}\cap \ldots \cap A_{n}$ uncountable $\rightarrow A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}$ are uncountable sets

or just

$A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots \cup A_{m}$ uncountable$\rightarrow A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}$ are uncountable sets.

Similarly, for the theorem

If $A_{n}$ is a countable set for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ is countable.

Is the contrapositive

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ is uncountable $\rightarrow A_{n}$ is an uncountable set for each $A_{n}$

or

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ is uncountable $\rightarrow$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_{n}$ is uncountable

or

$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ is uncountable $\rightarrow$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_{n}$ is uncountable

I hope these illustrations give some idea of the basis of my confusion (my apologies for the lame formatting).  Any clarifying remarks will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Embarrassing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to write such confusing statements using quantifiers, then applying De Morgan's law.

For your first example,

> If $A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots, A_{m}$ are all countable, then $A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots \cup A_{m}$ is countable.

Can be written as

> Given sets $A_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$, if $\forall i$, $A_i$ is countable, then $F(A_1,\ldots,A_m)$ is countable.

where $F(A_1,\ldots,A_m)=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots \cup A_{m}$.

Now the contrapositive canbe seen as

> Given sets $A_i$for $i=1,\ldots,m$, if $F(A_1,\ldots,A_m)$ is uncountable, then $\exists i$ such that $A_i$ is uncountable.

A similar approach can be taken with your second example.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two kinds of uses for the negation. It is true that when considered a complement (with respect to some fixed $X$) we have that $-(A\cup B)=-A\cap-B$.

But there is a separation between the **atomic proposition** of "$A\cup B$ is countable", and "the intersection of complements of $A$ and $B$ is uncountable".

The negation of "$A\cup B$ is countable" is simply "$A\cup B$ is *not* countable", or "$A\cup B$ is *uncountable*".

So what the contrapositive would mean, is that if $A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_m$ is uncountable, there exists at least one $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $A_i$ is uncountable.

Because the negation switches "every" and "some", but it does not switches unions and intersections.